# Where are source code of superset when I install it in virtual environment?

Tags: apache-superset

I have been struggling to find the source code of superset package when I install it in virtual environment. I followed [superset installation guide](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html) and then proceeded via virtual env.
Here are my virtual environment files:

[image]

I thought it will be in site-packages and so I navigated there also but found this (for both lib and lib64 folder):
[image]
Similarly for lib64:
[image]
Unlike the github file, there's no superset-frontend for customization as well. Does anyone know where can we locate these superset files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the compiled version, a binary file, as follows: `venv/bin/superset`. So when you use superset, it runs an optimized executable. The source files are at `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/`. The `pip install apache-superset` route is a quick out-of-the-box version of the install, it's not meant for customizing, so you'll change stuff but you won't see it reflected.

If you want to customize superset you have to [clone the github repo](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/) and follow [these instructions for installation](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#flask-server), which involve installing superset in editable mode! They explain how to install and run the frontend for dev work too. Don't skip the OS Dependencies part, I did the first time I installed it and you'll waste time at the long run!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure it was installed in a virtual environment it should be under envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset. If it doesn't exist there then it was installed in another location, please check and confirm

Comment: Yes, I did install it in virtual env and confirmed by checking the command outside too.